# Unable to sort dates with struct

Tags: c, struct

I've attempted to make a program which sorts a list of dates in the format of (month day year with year being the last two digits of the year. My program should sort the dates for years between 90 to 99 and then from 00 to 12.I can't get it to sort properly.

So for example if the input was this:

> January 1 01
>
> June 30 90
>
> October 1 01

It should sort it to

> October 1 01
>
> January 1 01
>
> June 30 90

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* constants for max chars, max day, max year, max size */
enum { MAXC = 12, MAX_DAY = 31, MAX_YEAR = 12, MAX_SIZE = 1000 };

typedef struct {
    char month[MAXC];   /* either make static or allocate separately */
    unsigned day;
    unsigned year;
} date;

/* empty character remaining in stdin */
void empty_stdin ()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}

/* sort struct date on year */
int sort (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    date *date1 = (date *) a;
    date *date2 = (date *) b;

    if (date2->year != date1->year)
        return (date1->year > date2->year) - (date1->year < date2->year);






    return 0;
}

/* output n elements of array of struct date */
void output (date *ar, int n)
{
    int i;

    printf ("\nOutput sorted by year:\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  %s %d %d\n", ar[i].month, ar[i].day, ar[i].year);
}

int main (void) {

    int i, n;
    date *ar = NULL;

    while (1) {     /* obtain valid 'n', compare with using fgets below */

        int rtn; /* varaible to save return of scanf -- always validate */

        //printf ("Enter number of dates to be entered (between 1 & 1000): ");
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &n)) != 1) {   /* if conversion failed */
            if (rtn == EOF) {   /* test for user cancelation of input */
                fprintf (stderr, "note: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
                return 0;
            }                   /* otherwise simply an invalid input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            goto tryagain;
        }

        if (n < 0) {            /* invalid input < 0 */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (n < 0).\n");
            goto tryagain;
        }

        if (n > MAX_SIZE) {     /* invalid input > MAX_SIZE */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (n > %d).\n", MAX_SIZE);
            goto tryagain;
        }

        break;      /* if we are here - we have a good value, break */

      tryagain:;    /* label for goto to jump over break */

        empty_stdin ();   /* empty characters that remain in input buffer */
    }

    empty_stdin ();     /* empty characters that remain in input buffer */

    /* allocate array of struct ar, n elements */
    if ((ar = malloc (sizeof *ar * n)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* provide format instructions */
    //printf ("Enter the date (month day year)\n"
           // "  format, e.g.:  Jan 18 2017\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n;) {   /* loop until all elements filled */

        char buf[MAX_DAY + 1] = "", ans[MAXC] = "";

        //printf (" date[%2d] : ", i + 1);    /* prompt for input */

        /* if fgets return is NULL, EOF encountered */
        if (fgets (buf, MAX_DAY + 1, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "note: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if (*buf == '\n') { /* if first char is '\n', user just hit enter */
            printf ("no input provided, quit (y/n)? ");
            if (fgets (ans, MAXC, stdin) && (*ans == 'y' || *ans == 'Y'))
                return 0;
            else if (!*ans) {   /* if ans NULL, EOF encountered */
                fprintf (stderr, "note: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /* parse with sscanf, validate 3 conversion took place */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%11s %u %u", ar[i].month, &ar[i].day, &ar[i].year) != 3)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            continue;
        }

        i++;    /* only increment if valid sscanf conversion took place */
    }

    qsort (ar, n, sizeof (date), sort);     /* sort by year */

    output (ar, n);     /* output results */

    free (ar);      /* free ar - you allocate it, you free it */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reduce it to a [mcve]. It's not for us the siphon out the irrelevant parts. You may find the problem yourself along the way.

Comment: Do `if(ar[i].year <= MAX_YEAR) ar[i].year += 2000; else ar[i].year += 1900;` after input `ar[i].year`. ... `printf ("....%u\n", ...., ar[i].year % 100);` after sort at `output`.

Comment: previous comment :  `%u` --> `%02u`.

Comment: if you want descending order, `return (date1->year > date2->year) - (date1->year < date2->year);` --> `return (date1->year < date2->year) - (date1->year > date2->year);`

Comment: I guess this is just a learning exercise, but my comment is *never use two-digit years*. Always use 4-digit years, and especially when you're writing computer programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably understand that this:

```
if (date2->year != date1->year)
    return (date1->year > date2->year) - (date1->year < date2->year);
```

does not make any sense whatsoever.

Here is what you want:

```
int year1 = fix_year( date1->year );
int year2 = fix_year( date2->year );
return year1 - year2;
```

where `fix_year()` is as follows:

```
int fix_year( int year )
{
    return (year >= 90? 2000 : 1900) + year;
}
```

which is another way of saying

```
int fix_year( int year )
{
    if( year >= 90 )
        return 1900 + year;
    return 2000 + year;
}
```

Note that later on you will also have to get rid of the `char month[MAXC];` member and replace it with an `int month;` because the lexicographical ordering of the names of the months in English (and in any language on earth I would be willing to guess) has absolutely no relation to the numbering of the months.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This issue has been driving me crazy for about the past 4 hours. Now I need to ask is there any way to flip the order of the output around so it goes from most recent date to the oldest date instead of the other way around?

Comment: Well yes, of course, just do `return year2 - year1;`

Comment: Oh I already assumed before commentating that you already knew that `return year2 - year1` doesn't work, well at least not in the example I used in my question. That's why I asked becuase I can't figure out why it doesn't just flip the output like it should.

Comment: Of course it will work, after using `fix_year()` on both year values.

Comment: Ah my mistake, it doesn't work becuase I'm still using char month[MAXC]; for month. How would I get it to work if I declare month as an int?

Comment: First you subtract years; if the result is non-zero, you return it, otherwise you proceed to subtract months; if the result is non-zero, you return it, otherwise you proceed to return the result of the subtraction of days.